# Recursive MySQL function

Tags: mysql

I need to find the clan someone is in. The only link to the clan is through the clan leader. Everyone is linked by someone else like a pyramid. I need to loop up through the members and find the top person.

EXAMPLE

```
tblClan
[ID][Name][Owner]
[1][My Clan][Tom]
[2][Another Clan][Fred]

tblAvatar
[Name][LinkedBy]
[Tom][null]
[Bel][Tom]
[Nathan][Bel]
[Mya][Fred]
[Fred][null]
```

What clan is Nathan in? Find Nathan, he's linked to Bel, find Bel, shes linked to Tom, find Tom, tom isnt linked to anyone... does he own a clan? Yes
Nathan belongs in My Clan

Currently I am using a recursive PHP function doing SELECT statements. How could I do this in 1 query instead of looping the same query?

Or another task is to count how many members are in the clan using a similar but reversed method.

Comment: mysql doesnt directly support with recursive queries. see this [blog post](http://guilhembichot.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html) to hack around this with stored procedures

Comment: Are all clans linked to porridge and the colour of tartan? On another less joval note you cannot do recursion with SQL.

Comment: Perhaps you should change the design of your database, what advantage are you getting out of structuring it like this?

Comment: Its on a Guardian, Disciple basis so a if a person changes Guardian they will be added to that Guardians clan by association. I may have a rethink of how I can do this.

Comment: This is known in the jargon as hierarchical querying. There are plenty of intertoobz resources about how to get MySQL applications to do it. I respectfully suggest you look at some, then ask another question if we can still help you.

Comment: Thank you Ollie :) Now I have a name for it I will look into it.